# Undefined property if value is null

Tags: php

I try validating select field in PHP. I prepared the code, but the interpretator return me this notice:

> Notice: Undefined property: Test5::$property in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/mvc3/controller/admin/test5.php on line 22 NULL

The problem occurs when I do not select anything from the list. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I presents code:

```
<form action="test5.php" method="post">
    <select name="select">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select...</option>
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Raspberry</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Pineaple</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="button">Send</button>
</form>
<?php
    class Test5 {
        private $paramName, $default;

        public function getParam($paramName, $default = null) {
            if (isset($_POST[$paramName])) {
                $this->property = trim($_POST[$paramName]);
            }
            return $this;
        }
        public function getProperty() {
            return $this->property;
        }
    }
    $test5 = new Test5;
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $test5->getParam('select', false);
        var_dump($test5->getProperty());
    }
?>
```

Comment: I didn't read carefully but this screamed at my face `$default = null`

Comment: Try adding $property the the private properties ` private $paramName, $default, $property;`

Answer (score 4):

You never set the property you're trying to get when you're selecting nothing from the list. Try to add the property `property` to the class. It will have `null` as default value :

```
private $property;
private $paramName;
private $default;
```

You can set a default value in constructor for example :

```
public function __construct() {
   $this->property = 'lorem ipsum';
}
```

Comment: No need to set it to `null`. If you define a property without assigning it a value, it will be `null` as default.

Comment: `__construct()` method isn't required. You can set the value when defining its visibility.  EX: `private $property = 'tacos';`

Answer (score 1):

You must define `$property` no matter what. So, you can do the following:

```
 class Test5 {
    private $paramName, $default;

    /**
     * Although the default is NULL, this 
     * demonstrates you can set to just about anything
    */
    private $property = null; 

    public function getParam($paramName, $default = null) {
        if (isset($_POST[$paramName])) {
            $this->property = trim($_POST[$paramName]);
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function getProperty() {
        return $this->property;
    }
}
$test5 = new Test5;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $test5->getParam('select', false);
    var_dump($test5->getProperty());
}
```

This will prevent that error as it is set by default. By *default* a property not *assigned* in a class returns `undefined` as it is not defined. By defining it with a null value give you some error checking room for input validation.

Check this out from the PHP Manual

[PHP: Properties - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: `var $property`? Using `var` is an old PHP4 relic. You should set the visibility instead. Just add it the same way the others are added: `private $paramName, $default, $property`. (better yet would be to set every var on it's own line with it's own visibility, though). If you don't assign it a value, it will be `null` by default.

Comment: Fair enough however as of *PHP 5.6* you can pre-define a value. So, I am demonstrating that ability in case the *op* isn't trying to have simply default returned. [PHP Manual page on this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: Now you've lost me. You _can_ still use `var $property = null;`, but using that is the same thing as `public $property = null;`, or even `public $property;`. In this case, it should probably be `private $property;` instead though. Why would you mix old and new style in the same class? Just keep it consistent. And I don't really understand what you mean with: _"PHP 5.6 you can pre-define a value"_?

Comment: That is why I used a reference @MagnusEriksson. I was not disagreeing. Good coding practice would use consistency **HOWEVER** that is why I used a reference which contains **EVERY** example you have mentioned, I have mentioned and some others have mentioned. Also, when I stated *"PHP 5.6 ou can pre-define a value"*, I was directly referencing my reference.... The PHP Manual...

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return NULL by default if no value is assigned, either assign some different default value (in the `if(isset($_POST[$paramName])` add an else that assigns some default value to property) or leave it as is. The notice just warns you about that and you can turn those notices off by adding `error_reporting(0);` above your class code.

Comment: No, please don't solve issues by turning off error reporting. Solve them instead.

Comment: Well yeah, solving is the way to go, just reminding him that he can hide that Notice, but it's being shown for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is undifiend you define it only if isset statment return true you need else statment also.

```
<form action="test5.php" method="post">
<select name="select">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select...</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Raspberry</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Pineaple</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="button">Send</button>
</form>
<?php
class Test5 {
    private $paramName, $default;

    public function getParam($paramName,  $default = null) {
        if (isset($_POST[$paramName])) {
            $this->property =    trim($_POST[$paramName]);
        }
else{ $this->property=" ";}
        return $this;
    }
    public function getProperty() {
        return $this->property;
    }
}
$test5 = new Test5;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $test5->getParam('select', false);
    var_dump($test5->getProperty());
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when this condition

```
if (isset($_POST[$paramName])) {
    $this->property = trim($_POST[$paramName]);
}
```

evaluates to `false` because a property with the name `property` doesn't exist in `Test5`.

However, if the condition evaluates to `true`, it will be dynamically created with `public` visibility when you assign it a value in the body of te condition.

To avoid the error, declare the property as already suggested:

```
class Test5
{
    private $property;

    // ...
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php